# Power BI - Relationships being ignored in Table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a simple Data model see below:
[image]

The issue I am having is the relationship between SFDC-CSAT_DATA and SFDC-Cases - Support.  When trying to create a Table on one of my pages, instead of only showing the records for the person I select (In this case myself), it is duplicating each record for every record in the cases table.  Sort of like an outer join:
[image]

In the table above, the first Case Number column is from the CSAT_DATA table, and the second one is from the Cases table.  in the Model above, the relationship between Cases and SFDC-ALL Cases works correctly.  What I've tried so far:

- Ensured the data types of the Case Number fields are identical in all tables
- Tried switching the direction of the join and the type
- Refreshing the data
- Checked there are no strange transformations happening.
- Tried connecting the Comments table directly to the Cases table, and excluding it altogether

Any ideas would be helpful,

Thanks,

Terry

Comment: Did u check your CSAT_Score calculation ?

Comment: Hi @bibakcamki, yes, the calculations are fine, thanks for responding.

Comment: the table that has CSAT_Score calculation is not being able to relate one of your column in the matrix table.  From the images i cannot guess more :(